# rails - how to visit a site that's running on thin server from another pc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app running in 2 different locations.  The first is a developer VM.  When I run the app on a thin server there, I can visit it from my desktop PC.  I also have the app running with (as far as I can tell) an identical configuration on another VM.  I am unable to view the site from my desktop when I try to connect there. Can anybody think of a reason?  I do have an Apache server running on the 2nd VM, is that an issue?

The exact nature of the failure is that when trying to connect from another location, the browser just never responds.  It doesn't display an error message or give a 404.  The loading graphic on the tab just continues to spin.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think Apache would be an issue unless you are trying to bind Apache and Thin to the same port.

Comment: Unable how?  Please provide details on the exact failure.

Comment: Jim, added description of failure.  Thanks.